# Why to add "extern" keyword if the global variable is external by default?

Tags: c++, linkage

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

extern int g_x; // this extern is a forward declaration of a variable named g_x that is defined somewhere else

int main()
{
    std::cout << g_x; // prints 2

    return 0;
}
```

add.cpp

```
int g_x { 2 };
```

If I delete extern in main.cpp, then the code does not work. One the other hand, I don't need extern in add.cpp. Global variables are external by default, but still. Is it because external linkage is a "one-sided relation" between two entities that are linked in different files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`extern` is different from *external linkage*. `extern` just means that you do a declaration, and that the variable is defined *somewhere else*.

If you remove `extern`, `int g_x` will be *defined* in `main.cpp` violating ODR (since you have it defined twice).

Comment: I think, `extern` could sometimes also mean *external linkage*. If `g_x` had type `const int` in add.cpp, then we would have to make it `extern const int g_x` instead in add.cpp. Is that correct?
(because we cannot access to add.cpp from main.cpp since `const` is not external)

Comment: It is also interesting, that for the functions we wouldn't use `extern` in this case at all. Hmm.

Comment: @Mihail, you are right, if you add `extern` to a *definition*, this object has external linkage: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Programming/Programming_Languages/C%2B%2B/Code/Keywords/extern#:~:text=extern%20const%20int%20k%20%3D%201,the%20scope%20of%20multiple%20files. Curiously enough, I've never used external in this way. I wonder if I am doing something right or am missing out.